# Adding an ASP.Net button in code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I've got a pretty tight form with an AJAX Accordion pane.  I'm using a Master page, but the ASPX child page looks like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="MyUpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:panel ID="MyContent" runat="server">

    <!--  ************************************  -->
                    <ajaxtoolkit:modalpopupextender id="MdlCommentsExtender" runat="server"     
                        targetcontrolid="MyContent" popupcontrolid="pnlComments" 
                        popupdraghandlecontrolid="PopupHeader" drag="True" 
                        backgroundcssclass="ModalPopupBG" Enabled="False"  >
                    </ajaxtoolkit:modalpopupextender>

                    <asp:panel id="pnlComments" style="display: none" runat="server" BackColor="White" CssClass="modalPopup">
                        <div class="HellowWorldPopup">
                            <div class="PopupHeader" id="Div3" style="border: thin solid #000000; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; background-color: #C0C0C0; color: #000000; font-weight: bold; height: 40px;" ><br />Pend Comment</div>
                                <div class="PopupBody" style="background-color: #FFFFFF">
                                    <table style="width: 300px">
                                        <tr style="text-align:left">
                                            <td style="padding:4px"><asp:Label ID="lblCommentBox" runat="server" Text="Comment:"></asp:Label></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding:4px">
                                           <!--     <asp:TextBox ID="txtCommentBox_Old" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" TextMode="multiline" Wrap="True" Height="70px" Width="270px" Font-Size="Small"></asp:TextBox>  -->
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCommentBox" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="textbox" Wrap="True" Height="70px" Width="270px" Font-Size="Small" Rows="3" runat="server"  onkeyup="textCounter(this, this.form.remLen, 50);" onkeydown="textCounter(this, this.form.remLen, 50);" onpaste="textCounter(this, this.form.remLen, 50);" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>  
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="remLen" name="remLen" size="2" maxlength="3" value="50" /> characters left
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <div class="Controls">
                                    <table style="width: 300px">
                                        <tr>
                                           <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center"> <asp:Button ID="mdlCmntsOk_Click" runat="server" Text="OK" CssClass="textbox" Height="28px" Width="75px" OnClick="mdlCommentsOk_Click" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </asp:panel>
            </asp:panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <!--  ************************************  -->

</asp:Content>
```

This form contains a modalpopupextender which I would like to call from an "Edit" button.  The Accordion is being added dynamically via code-behind.  My entire code-behind looks like this:

```
public partial class frmBenefitSummaryList : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string ConnStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnCST"].ConnectionString;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        BindAccordions();
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            MdlCommentsExtender.Show();
        }
    }

    private void BindAccordions()
    {
        #region Get the value from the database

         DataTable dt = new DataTable();   
         try   
         {   

             using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())   
             {
                 connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnCST"].ToString();   
                 connection.Open();   
                 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();   
                 cmd.Connection = connection;
                 string CmdTxt = "Select CBL.ID, CBL.[Category], CBL.[Provision], CTL.MarkForReview, CTL.IssueType, CTL.Resolution, CTL.Feedback, CTL.TemplateID";
                 CmdTxt = CmdTxt + " from [tblCSTBenefitList] CBL";
                 CmdTxt = CmdTxt + " LEFT JOIN tblCSTTemplateList CTL";
                 CmdTxt = CmdTxt + " ON CBL.ID = CTL.BenefitID";
                 CmdTxt = CmdTxt + " where CBL.ID > '0'";
                 CmdTxt = CmdTxt + " ORDER BY CBL.[Category], CBL.[Provision] ASC";

                 cmd.CommandText = CmdTxt; 
                 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;   
                 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);   

                 da.Fill(dt);   
                 cmd.Dispose();   
                 connection.Close();   
             }   
         }
         catch (Exception ex) { Response.Write(ex.Message); }

        #endregion

        #region Create accordion with properties

        Accordion acrDynamic = new Accordion();
        acrDynamic.ID = "MyAccordion";
        acrDynamic.SelectedIndex = -1;//No default selection   
        acrDynamic.RequireOpenedPane = false;//no open pane   
        acrDynamic.HeaderCssClass = "accordionHeader";//Header class   
        acrDynamic.HeaderSelectedCssClass = "accordionHeaderSelected";//Selected herder class   
        acrDynamic.ContentCssClass = "accordionContent";//Content class  

        #endregion

        #region Create the panes

        Label lbTitle;   
        Label lbContent;   
        AccordionPane pane;   
        string Content = "";


        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)   
        {
            if (Content == "")
                Content += "<table class='hoverTable'><tr><th bgcolor='#5D7B9D' width='440px'><font color='#fff'>Provision</th><th bgcolor='#5D7B9D' width='120px'><font color='#fff'>Mark For Review</th><th bgcolor='#5D7B9D' width='120px'><font color='#fff'>Issue Type</th><th bgcolor='#5D7B9D' width='120px'><font color='#fff'>Resolution</th><th bgcolor='#5D7B9D' width='120px'><font color='#fff'>Feedback</th><th bgcolor='#5D7B9D' width='60px'><font color='#fff'>Edit</th></tr>";

            string BranchName = dt.Rows[i]["Category"].ToString();   
            string Next_Branch = "";   

            if (i != dt.Rows.Count - 1)   
                Next_Branch = dt.Rows[i + 1]["Category"].ToString();

            Content += "<tr>";
            Content += "<td>" + dt.Rows[i]["Provision"].ToString() + "</td>";
            Content += "<td>" + dt.Rows[i]["MarkForReview"].ToString() + "</td>";
            Content += "<td>" + dt.Rows[i]["IssueType"].ToString() + "</td>";
            Content += "<td>" + dt.Rows[i]["Resolution"].ToString() + "</td>";
            Content += "<td>" + dt.Rows[i]["Feedback"].ToString() + "</td>";
            Content += "<td><input type=\"submit\" ID=\"btnEdit\" name=\"ctl00$MainContent$btnEdit_OnClick\" onserverclick=\"btnEdit_OnClick()\" UseSubmitBehavior=\"False\" value=\"Edit\" /></td>";
            Content += "</tr>"; 

            if (BranchName != Next_Branch) //if last row of branch   
            {
                Content += "</table>";
                pane = new AccordionPane();   
                lbTitle = new Label();   
                lbContent = new Label();   
                pane.ID = "Pane_" + BranchName.ToString();   
                lbTitle.Text = BranchName;   
                pane.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(lbTitle);   
                lbContent.Text = Content;   
                pane.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(lbContent);   
                acrDynamic.Panes.Add(pane);   
                Content = "";   
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Add the accordion to the page

        MyContent.Controls.Add(acrDynamic);

        #endregion

    }

    protected void btnEdit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MdlCommentsExtender.Enabled = true;
        MdlCommentsExtender.Show();
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).SetFocus(this.txtCommentBox);
    }

    protected void mdlCommentsOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MdlCommentsExtender.Hide();
    }
}
```

That's it.  That's all my code.  And it runs like a champ.  Except one thing: the current Edit button is created by this line in the in the `#region Create the panes` section:

```
Content += "<td><input type=\"submit\" ID=\"btnEdit\" name=\"ctl00$MainContent$btnEdit_OnClick\" onserverclick=\"btnEdit_OnClick()\" UseSubmitBehavior=\"False\" value=\"Edit\" /></td>";
```

This causes a postback, and that negates my modal form.  So, what I need to do is change that to an asp:Button button so I can call my modal window.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?  Assume I'm an idiot (because I kind of am) and be explicit in your explanation, please.

Comment: I know this is maybe a lot of rework but shouldn't it be easier if you created real controls (HtmlTable, HtmlRow, HtmlCell) and then added the Button in that control collection? Because that would give you the asp.net magic you seem to be looking for. By going down the route with a string concat (btw lookup StringBuilder) you're on your own and integration is then a real nightmare.

Comment: you could try `Content += "<td><input type=\"button\" ID=...` instead. This won't cause a postback when the button is clicked.

Comment: VDWWD - I tried changing it to button and it still posted back.  I put a break on my page load and have a small "if (Page.IsPostback)" and it entered that block whether I had it as a button or a submit.

Comment: @rene - Can you post an answer that shows your solution?  99% of my code is above, so you should have all the info you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would always try to prevent creating html markup in the code-behind, specially if you still plan on leveraging the ASP.NET pipeline. If you can make sure your controltree is regenerated on page load, your changed code would look like this:

```
Table table = null;

string BranchName = null;

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    TableRow tr;
    if (BranchName != dt.Rows[i]["Category"].ToString())
    {
        BranchName = dt.Rows[i]["Category"].ToString();
        // setup pane
        pane = new AccordionPane();
        // add pane to accordion
        acrDynamic.Panes.Add(pane);

        // pane content
        lbTitle = new Label();
        pane.ID = "Pane_" + BranchName;
        lbTitle.Text = BranchName;
        pane.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(lbTitle);

        // pane container will have the table
        table = new Table();
        // set properties like class, height .. etc
        table.CssClass = "hoverTable";
        // add it to a container
        pane.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(table);

        // top row
        tr = new TableRow();
        // cells
        TableHeaderCell th = new TableHeaderCell();
        th.Width = 440;
        th.Text = "Provision";
        // set other properties
        tr.Controls.Add(th);
        // create next control
        th = new TableHeaderCell();
        th.Width = 120;
        th.Text = "Mark for Review";
        // set other properties
        tr.Controls.Add(th);
        // etc for other columns
        table.Controls.Add(tr);

    }

    tr = new TableRow();
    TableCell tc = new TableCell();
    tc.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Provision"].ToString();
    tr.Controls.Add(tc);
    tc = new TableCell();
    tc.Text = dt.Rows[i]["MarkForReview"].ToString();
    tr.Controls.Add(tc);
    // etc for other columns
    // add the button
    tc = new TableCell();
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Text = "Edit";
    button.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
    button.Click += new EventHandler(btnEdit_OnClick);
    tc.Controls.Add(button);
    tr.Controls.Add(tc);

    table.Controls.Add(tr);
}
```

I wasn't sure about the Name and ID. I expect the control will get a proper name and id in the Render method of the Button control.

Comment: This worked for 1 pane, but none of the others showed up.  And I got an error when I tried to add the button.Click line: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.EventHandler'.  Any idea how to fix these?

Comment: I fixed the button.Click for you and fixed the pane bug .... (changed the static 0 to use `i` ...)

Comment: This works nicely.  One last question and I won't bug you; I've got a class I've assigned to the table in my code (<table class='hoverTable'>).  It basicalls adds some CSS so that whichever row you're hovering above changes color.  Can you assign a class to a table using this code?  If so, how would I do it?

Comment: @JohnnyBones added that as well for you ... `table.CssClass = "hoverTable";`